# What would cause a list index of range for this function that iterates through PyTrend keywords?

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, google-trends

thank you for looking at my question.

I am iterating through Google trends data using the pseudo google trends API PyTrends. When I use the google trends website it is fine with me using multiple words together so long as I use the "+" symbol in between words. For example: "a-kasse+akasse+arbejdsformidling+arbejdsformidlinger+dagpenge+dagpengeperiode". When I use a single word in my code, the program works as expected. But when I use multiple words concatenated it breaks.

When I use the following function, it throws a list index out of range error:

```
def my_funct(Keyword, Dates, Country, Col_name):
 
    KEYWORDS=[Keyword] 

    KEYWORDS_CODES=[pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)[0] for i in KEYWORDS] 

    df_CODES= pd.DataFrame(KEYWORDS_CODES)

    EXACT_KEYWORDS=df_CODES['mid'].to_list()

    DATE_INTERVAL= Dates
    COUNTRY=[Country] #Use this link for iso country code
    CATEGORY=0 # Use this link to select categories
    SEARCH_TYPE='' #default is 'web searches',others include 'images','news','youtube','froogle' (google shopping)


    Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD = list(zip(*[iter(EXACT_KEYWORDS)]*1))
    Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD = [list(x) for x in Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD]
    dicti = {}
    i = 1

    for Country in COUNTRY:
        for keyword in Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD:
            try:
                pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=keyword, 
                                      timeframe = DATE_INTERVAL,
                                      geo = Country, 
                                      cat = CATEGORY,
                                      gprop = SEARCH_TYPE) 
                dicti[i] = pytrend.interest_over_time()
                i+=1
                time.sleep(9)
                print(dicti)
                
            except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
                    print("Timeout occured")
        
    df_trends = pd.concat(dicti, axis=1)


    df_trends.columns = df_trends.columns.droplevel(0) #drop outside header
    df_trends = df_trends.drop('isPartial', axis = 1) #drop "isPartial"
    df_trends.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True) #reset_index
    df_trends.columns=['date', Col_name] #change column names
  

    return df_trends
```

I execute that function through another function as follows:

```
df_merged3 = excelConcatFunct("a-kasse+akasse+arbejdsformidling+arbejdsformidlinger+dagpenge+dagpengeperiode", 'DK', 'DANISH search terms')
```

And here is how that function works:

```
def excelConcatFunct(Word, Country_code, Col_name):

# generic plug-n-chug data
x1 = my_funct(Word, '2004-01-04 2009-01-04', Country_code, Col_name)
x2 = my_funct(Word, '2009-01-05 2014-01-05', Country_code, Col_name)
x3 = my_funct(Word, '2014-01-06 2019-01-06', Country_code, Col_name)              
x4 = my_funct(Word, '2019-01-07 {0}'.format(Today), Country_code, Col_name)      

# generic plug-n-chug data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(x3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(x4)

# Creates an empty dataframe to add to merged df for column spacing
df0 = pd.DataFrame()
df0[''] = ''

# this concats the df horizontally
df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df0, df2, df0, df3, df0, df4], axis=1)
df_merged.reset_index(inplace=True)
# This removes the dangling last column that said "Unamed:0"
df_merged = df_merged.loc[:, ~df_merged.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
# This removes the dangling first index column
df_merged = df_merged.loc[:, ~df_merged.columns.str.contains('^index')]

# returns the merged dataframe 
return df_merged
```

And here is the error message I am getting:

```
  File "C:\Users\JohnReese\Desktop\G_Trends\G_Trender.py", line 111, in <module>
    df_merged3 = excelConcatFunct("a-kasse+akasse+arbejdsformidling+arbejdsformidlinger+dagpenge+dagpengeperiode", 'DK', 'DANISH search terms')

  File "C:\Users\JohnReese\Desktop\G_Trends\G_Trender.py", line 83, in excelConcatFunct
    x1 = my_funct(Word, '2004-01-04 2009-01-04', Country_code, Col_name)

  File "C:\Users\JohnReese\Desktop\G_Trends\G_Trender.py", line 31, in my_funct
    KEYWORDS_CODES=[pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)[0] for i in KEYWORDS]

  File "C:\Users\JohnReese\Desktop\G_Trends\G_Trender.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
    KEYWORDS_CODES=[pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)[0] for i in KEYWORDS]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please help. Any and all help is welcomed.

Thank you!

Comment: Check what `pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)` returns.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 It prints nothing out. Very strange.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 when I use a single word like "Unemployment", it will print. Prints this: [{'mid': '/m/07s_c', 'title': 'Unemployment', 'type': 'Topic'}]